# Reset/Change Picker(Dropdown) selectedValue with setNativeProps

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a form with a TextInput, a Picker and a TouchableHiglight.

User will enter something into the TextInput, pick an item from the Picker and submit with the TouchableHighlight.

I am able to use ref to reset the TextInput but I can't figure out how to change/reset the Picker value to default.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection 
>   TypeError: this.value2ref.setNativeProps is not a function

**React-Native**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    value1: '',
    value1ref: '',
    value2: '',
    value2ref: ''
  }
}

<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({value1:text})}
  ref={input => {this.value1ref=input}}
/>

<View>
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.value1}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({value2: itemValue})}
    ref={input => {this.value2ref=input}}>
    <Picker.Item label="Pick an item" value="" />
    <Picker.Item label="Item 1" value="Item1" />
    <Picker.Item label="Item 2" value="Item2" />
    <Picker.Item label="Item 3" value="Item3" />
  </Picker>
</View>

<View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <View>
      <Text>SUBMIT</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I've also tried with this type of reference but to no avail.

```
ref={component => this._exampleref=component}>
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
onSubmit() {
  this.value1ref.setNativeProps({ //This one works
    text: "",
  });
  this.value2ref.setNativeProps({ // This one does NOT work
    selectedValue: "",
  });
}
```

I know I can use `this.value1ref.clear()` but i'm doing it this way to prove a point, and also, there is no `clear()` for the Picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are supposed to be using refs for that.

You are correctly updating the state with the callbacks in `onChangeText` and `onValueChange` but you are not rendering from the state, for that you need to add the `value` prop to the `TextInput` you were already using a `selectedValue` for the picker hence the different behavior (the value used in the prop was probably the wrong one though).

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({value1:text})}
  value={this.state.value1}
/>
```

and

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.value2}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({value2: itemValue})}
  >
  {/* ... */}
</Picker>
```

With that set you just need this in your onSubmit.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.setState({value1: '', value2: ''});
}
```

Comment: I tried playing around with states but it just wasn't working so I looked for another way. It must've been super late at night... cause I remember doing `this.state.value1 = '';` instead of what you suggested `this.setState({value1: ''});`. Well, this is embarrassing. Thanks for clearing that up! Maybe tonight I'll be able to sleep without having Picker/Dropdown nightmares haha